# Como personalizar tags em ruby on rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Tenho um formulário:

```
<% form_tag :action => 'validacao' do %>
      <p> Login: <%= text_field :acesso, :email %></p>
      <p> Senha: <%= password_field :acesso, :password %></p>
      <p><%= submit_tag 'Entrar' %></p>
<% end %>
```

Como colocar propriedades como `class` no `text_field`, no `password_field` e no botão `submit_tag`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muito obrigado, mas não precisa mais, continuei pesquisando e encontrei as resposta bem aqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658054/rails-and-haml-how-to-add-id-and-class-selectors-to-link-to-helper

Basta usar da seguinte forma:

```
<% form_tag :action => 'validacao' do %>
<p class="form-inline"> Login: <%= text_field :acesso, :email, :class => "form-control" %></p>
  <p class="form-inline"> Senha: <%= password_field :acesso, :password, :class => "form-control" %></p>
  <p><%= submit_tag 'Entrar', :class => "btn btn-default" %></p>
<% end %>
```